# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, String, Int

Tags: java, string, integer, int, row

My eror in program is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at knapsacproject.Interface.jButton4ActionPerformed(Interface.java:221)
```

this code is for button, which prints the result in **jTextField4** ,but nothing writes

my code in java :

```
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
 int nRow = model.getRowCount();
 try{
 algorithm algo = new algorithm(getTableData(model, 1),getTableData(model, 2),
Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText)),
Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText)),Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
int[] result = algo.getResult();
for(int i = 0; i <nRow;i++) {
if(result[i]==1)
model.setValueAt("take", i , 3);
else
model.setValueAt("leave", i, 3);
}
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new StatusColumnCellRenderer());
jTextField4.setText(Integer.toString(result[nRow]));
```

and eror is in line :

```
jTextField4.setText(Integer.toString(result[nRow]));
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `result[nRow-1]` instead of `result[nRow]` like this:

```
 jTextField4.setText(Integer.toString(result[nRow-1]));
```

Because the index of array start from `0` to `nRow-1` not `nRow`.

Comment: Thank you, it's ok

Answer (score 2):

`result` array size is `nRow` but you are trying to access element with index `nRow` and you can't do that as array starting index is `0` in java. My guess you need to change the problem line to:

```
jTextField4.setText(Integer.toString(result[nRow-1]));
```

Comment: Thank you, it's ok